# Not getting status code 429 and customized error message while using AspNetCoreRateLimit

Tags: .net-core

I have implemented rate-limiting middleware in my .net core Api application using the AspNetCoreRateLimit nuget package. The rules that have i have set in the appsettings.json file is working. However i am not getting the Response code 429 and the customized message. instead it shows **(failed)net::ERR_FAILED** in the status column.
Here's my code from the startup file.

```
services.AddOptions();
services.AddMemoryCache();
services.Configure<IpRateLimitOptions>(config.GetSection("IpRateLimiting"));
services.AddSingleton<IIpPolicyStore, MemoryCacheIpPolicyStore>();
services.AddSingleton<IRateLimitCounterStore, MemoryCacheRateLimitCounterStore>();
services.AddSingleton<IRateLimitConfiguration, RateLimitConfiguration>();
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

and here's the config data from appsetting.json file

```
 "IpRateLimiting": {
    "EnableEndpointRateLimiting": true,
    "StackBlockedRequests": false,
    "RealIpHeader": "X-Real-IP",
    "ClientIdHeader": "X-ClientId",
    "HttpStatusCode": 429,
    "QuotaExceededMessage": "API calls quota exceeded",
    "GeneralRules": [
      {
        "Endpoint": "*:/api/*",
        "Period": "1m",
        "Limit": 20
      }
    ]
  }
```

Here my requests are getting blocked after the 20th attempt however neither do i get the response code as **429** nor do i get the "**API calls quota exceeded**" message set in the **QuotaExceededMessage** property. 
Am i missing something?

Here's the Code from my Startup.cs file

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        //This is where i have configured the Rate limit settings using extension method
           services.ConfigureRateLimitSettings(Configuration);  

            services.AddMvc(options =
            {
        options.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true;
                options.ReturnHttpNotAcceptable = true;
            }).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

            services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
            services.ConfigureCORS(Configuration);
            services.ConfigureSwagger();
            services.ConfigureDBContext(Configuration);
            services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));
        }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseIpRateLimiting();
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseCORSExtension();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseStaticFilesExtension(Configuration);
            app.UseMvc();
            app.UseSwaggerExtension();
        }
```

And here is the extension method for ConfigureRateLimitSettings

```
public static void ConfigureRateLimitSettings(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration config)
   {
                services.AddOptions();
                services.AddMemoryCache();
                services.Configure<IpRateLimitOptions>(config.GetSection("IpRateLimiting"));
                services.AddSingleton<IIpPolicyStore, MemoryCacheIpPolicyStore>();
                services.AddSingleton<IRateLimitCounterStore, MemoryCacheRateLimitCounterStore>();
                services.AddSingleton<IRateLimitConfiguration, RateLimitConfiguration>();
                //services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
    }
```

Comment: Can you add all of the code in `Startup.cs`?

Comment: @dustyhoppe : i have added the code from my startup file.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to resolve this. I have just changed the position of my app.UseIpRateLimiting(); i have placed it after app.UseCORSExtension() and             app.UseAuthentication();

So now my code is as follows

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseCORSExtension();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseIpRateLimiting(); -- Placed it here
        app.UseStaticFilesExtension(Configuration);
        app.UseMvc();
        app.UseSwaggerExtension();
    }
```

Now i am able to get the response code as **429 Too Many Requests**.
Thanks everyone for your time.